# How to use simple salesforce (python library for salesforce) to add ShippingAddress field?

Tags: upsert, python, address, simple-salesforce

I have tried to upsert an account with ShippingAddress using [simple salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) However, I am getting the error:

```
[{u'errorCode': u'JSON_PARSER_ERROR', u'message': u'Cannot deserialize instance of ShippingAddress from VALUE_STRING value abc or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:31]'}]
```

Below is my query.

```
    sf.Account.upsert(
        'Custom_Id__c/abc123',
        {
            'Name': 'abc',
            'RecordTypeId': '0121U000000G51AbC',
            'ShippingAddress': {        
                'City': 'abc',
                'Country': 'USA',
                'Street': 'Town Hall',
                'CountryCode': None,
                'PostalCode': None,
                'State': None,
                'StateCode': None,      
                'Accuracy': None,
                'Latitude': None,
                'Longitude': None,                  
            }               
        },
```

Any idea on how I can upsert shipping address properly using simple salesforce?

Comment: You will need to prefix the fields with the address in context. In this case e.g., `ShippingCity`, `ShippingStreet`, etc.

Comment: @JayantDas This time I am getting a different error and it's `Cannot deserialize instance of ShippingAddress from VALUE_NULL value null or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:43]'}`

Comment: I don't know the working details of simple salesforce but I don't think you need `ShippingAddress` attribute at all. Just the individual field names and values.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks! that seems to have worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have any experience working with simple-salesforce and neither I am associated with it anyway.

But based on how the [Address Compound Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) works and just by looking at [simple-salesforce docs](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/), seems you just need to use the individual compound field names here in your request without having the `ShippingAddress` attribute.

Your request should look as:

```
sf.Account.upsert(
    'Custom_Id__c/abc123',
    {
        'Name': 'abc',
        'RecordTypeId': '0121U000000G51AbC',
        'ShippingCity': 'abc',
        'ShippingStreet': 'Town Hall',
         ...
    }
)
```